# How do I permanently change a list after user's input?

Tags: python, list, append, extends

```
hiddenWords = ['hello', 'hi', 'surfing']
print("Would you like to enter a new list of words or end the game? L/E?")
    decision  = input()
    if decision == 'L':
        print('Enter a new list of words')
        newString = input()
        newList = newString.split()
        hiddenWords.extend(newList)
        j = random.randint(0, len(hiddenWords) - 1)
        secretWord = hiddenWords[j]
        exit(0)
```

How do I permanently add the input of the user to the hiddenWords list so that next time I open the application the words the user has entered has been extended onto the hiddenWords list?

Thanks.
This Code is part of a main body of code.

Comment: You would have to write code to edit the literal in the actual Python code file - although this is possible, it would be **much easier** to save the list to a file (e.g. using `pickle`, `csv`, `json`, ...) and load it in each time the script runs.

Answer (score 3):

When you write

```
hiddenWords = ['hello', 'hi', 'surfing']
```

You are, each time the program runs, defining the variable `hiddenWords` as `['hello', 'hi', 'surfing']` .
So no matter what you extend after this, every time the code runs the line above, it will redefine to that value.

What you are looking for actually is to use a Database, such as SQLite, to store values so that you can retrieve them at any time.
Also, you can save data in a file and read this everytime, which is a simpler way.

Comment: A database is a heavy lift for such as simple task.

Comment: I agree, but I don't know how big his project can get.

Answer (score 1):

When your program exits, all variables are lost, because variables only exit in memory. In order to save your modification accross program executions (everytime you run your script), you need to save the data onto the Disk, i.e: write it to a file. Pickle is indeed the simplest solution.

Answer (score 0):

I like json. This would be a possible solution:

```
import json

words = []
try:
  f = open("words.txt", "r")
  words = json.loads(f.read())
  f.close()
except:
  pass

print("list:")
for word in words:
  print(word)
print("enter a word to add it to the list or return to exit")
add = raw_input() # for python3 you need to use input()

if add:
  words.append(add)
  try:
    f = open("words.txt", "w")
    f.write(json.dumps(words, indent=2))
    f.close()
    print("added " + add)
  except:
    print("failed to write file")
```

If you want to add multiple words at a time use this.

```
import json

words = []
try:
  f = open("words.txt", "r")
  words = json.loads(f.read())
  f.close()
except:
  pass

print("list:")
for word in words:
  print(word)

save = False
while True:
  print("enter a word to add it to the list or return to exit")
  add = raw_input() # for python3 you need to use input()
  if add:
    words.append(add)
    print("added " + add)
    save = True
  else:
    break

if save:
  try:
    f = open("words.txt", "w")
    f.write(json.dumps(words, indent=2))
    f.close()
  except:
    print("failed to write file")
```

Comment: A couple of issues... you don't initialize `words` if the file doesn't exist and you should use `json.load` instead of `json.loads`.

Comment: I initialize words if the file doesn't exist in line 3. I could use json.load but this is more clear because both json methods are working with strings and everybody knows that file.read() returns a string.

Comment: How would I add more than 1 word at a time?

Comment: make a while loop that waits for words until the user enters something specific like for example return, i will add this  to the answer soon

Comment: Ok, I just gave my suggestion but I would like to see the loop.

Comment: there you go, added the loop to the answer